# C# specflow how to update the codebehind when new scenario added in feature file

Tags: c#, specflow

I am new to specflow.
I am trying to write a test for my asp.net core webapi test. I added the new scenario to the existing .feature file. the feature file has got corresponding code behind file i.e .cs. My new scenario is not getting generated in the .cs file. I have got specflow extension in my visual studio 2019.

.feature:

```
Scenario: Updating a scoring type to unarchive a valid archived audit, passed in and updated
    Given I log in as 'Zoe'
    When I do a 'put' for the endpoint 'api/types/1/unarchive' with the following parameters
        | Name | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
    Then I get Status Code 'NoContent' response
```

But my .cs only showing the old scenario and due to this my test is not showing up in test explorer. How to generate or update the .cs file with my new scenario?

Thanks

Comment: After enable Tools -> Specflow -> EnableSpecFlowSingleFileGenerator to true and right click 'Run Custom Tool' updated the .cs file with the new scenario added.

Answer (score 0):

After enable Tools -> Specflow -> EnableSpecFlowSingleFileGenerator to true and right click 'Run Custom Tool' updated the .cs file with the new scenario added

[image]